# Redshift / Regular Expression (Negative Lookahead) does not work

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

When I use negative lookahead (something like `(?!abc)`) on redshift,
redshift returns the error like this:

```
-- Find records that do not start with abc
select * from table_a where column_a ~ '^(?!abc).+$'
```

> Error: PG::InternalError: ERROR: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '^(?>>>HERE>>>!abc).+$'. DETAIL: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression: '^(?>>>HERE>>>!abc).+$'. code: 8002 context: T_regexp_init query: 1039510 location: funcs_expr.cpp:130

It looks like Redshift does not recognize negative lookahead...
Is there any way I can use it on Redshift?

Comment: And what is your intent? What you need to match? A string not equal to `abc`? Redshift regex flavor is  POSIX, so no lookarounds are available.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I updated the question to show my intent. But no lookarounds are available...? :(

Comment: So, you want to match any entry that does not start with `abc`? Try `where column_a !~ '^abc'` (not sure how to use negation properly though)

Comment: Everything before the regex string (select * from table_a where column_a ~ ) is hard coded to another system, so I kinda needed a way to negate the expression without !~. But looking at your comments, I figured it's so much easier to use !~. So I'll talk to the engineer who wrote that code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acc. to the [Amazon Redshift documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html), the regular expressions you can use with `~` operator comply with the POSIX standard. That means **there is no lookaround support** and you cannot use `(?!...)`, nor `(?<!...)` constructs in these patterns.

It seems that you want to match a string if it does not start with a pattern. In this case, you may use the *negated* regex operator version, `!~`.

```
where column_a !~ '^abc'
```

Comment: Redshift now supports Perl Regex syntax if you pass 'p' in paramters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

Comment: @dineshygv Ok, nice to know, but this question is about the use of regex with the tilde operator, not `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.