# RegEx — Optional substring in positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift's `stl_query` to select `querytxt` from `stl_load_commits` queries. I would like to transform the `querytxt` column using RegEx to just get the schema and table name.

I have some queries like the following:

1. `COPY schema.table ...`
2. `COPY ANALYZE schema.table ...`
3. `copy schema.table ...`
4. `copy analyze schema.table ..`
5. `copy table ...`

I want to use RegEx to match from the beginning of the string by ignoring `COPY` and `ANALYZE` and getting the `schema` or `schema.table` after `COPY` (or `ANALYZE` if exists). `COPY` and `ANALYZE` matching needs to be case insensitive.

So the results would be:

1. `schema.table`
2. `scehma.table`
3. `schema.table`
4. `schema.table`
5. `table`

I was hoping something like this would work but it's not: `(?<=^COPY (?:ANALYZE ))\S*`

**BONUS**:

I have a string like this:

`copy "schema"."table" ...`

The previous RegEx solution should find `"schema"."table"` but if it can select `schema.table` instead that would be great!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Regexp functions are vendor-specific.

Comment: Unless you have a specific database, then "sql" is  not appropriate.  This is especially true because not all databases support regular expressions, and those that do often have different implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capture group here with some optional logic:

```
\bCOPY (?:ANALYZE )?((?:\S+?\.)?\S+)
```

Please use the regex in case insensitive mode.

If you want to extract this information in a SQL query, you may try something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(query), '^copy (analyze )?(\\S+).*$', '$2')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: This works!  Was able to trim it down to ```\bCOPY (?:ANALYZE )?(\S+)``` for my use case. 
But not sure how to use this RegEx in Redshift? Seems like Redshift doesn't support look arounds? https://regex101.com/r/C6Ulrg/3/

Comment: You can't use lookarounds in Redshift regex.  I thought you were just using some text editor to parse SQL code.

Comment: Bummer... I guess I might have to export and parse separately. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @hcas Check my updated answer for a Redshift query which you may use to extract the table or schema-table names.  The demo is in Postgres (best I could do), so the syntax changes a little.

Comment: getting this error: ```[XX000] ERROR: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'copy (?>>>HERE>>>:analyze )'.```. Maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022295/redshift-regular-expression-negative-lookahead-does-not-work

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to work. It's not error-ing out anymore but I am getting the full query back as the result

Comment: Check the updated answer (not the comments).  What I have there should be working now.

Comment: Still getting the full query back (but lowercased). Maybe I'm doing something wrong, here is the full query:

```select
        slc.query as query_id,
        trim(slc.filename) as file,
        slc.curtime as updated,
        slc.lines_scanned as rows,
        sq.querytxt as querytxt,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(sq.querytxt), '^copy (analyze )?(\S+).*$', '$2')  as t
from stl_load_commits slc
    join stl_query sq on sq.query = slc.query
where trunc(slc.curtime) = '2020-05-07'
limit 10```

Comment: If you're getting back the full text, then it means the pattern isn't matching.  This is as much help as I can offer you, unfortunately, because I don't have Redshift in front of me.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the extra effort help! I'll try a bit more, otherwise just export and parse it out with code

Comment: figured it out @TimBiegeleisen. ```^copy (analyze )?(\\S+).*$```. Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Comment: @hcas Tricky one, that double backslash `\\S`.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

`(?i)^\s+COPY\s+(?:ANALYZE\s+)?("?)([^"]+)\1\.([^"]?)(\S+)\2` and look for groups 2 and 4 in the match.

Case insensitive. Find any whitespace after start of line, then the word "COPY", and least some space, then optionally "analyze" plus any whitespace, then a word surrounded by quotes maybe, then a literal dot, then another word surrounded by quotes maybe.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working? https://regex101.com/r/VO9fww/1

Comment: `(?i)^\s*COPY\s+(?:ANALYZE\s+)?("?)([^."]+)\1\.("?)([^"\s]+)\3`

Comment: won't work in redshift because of look arounds but thanks for detail regex response!

Comment: What's a lookaround? There are no zero-width look-ahead- or look-behind-assertions here.