# How to strip ending date from string using Regex? - SQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I want to format the strings in a table column, in a specific format.

Input table:

```
file_paths
my-file-path/wefw/wefw/2022-03-20
my-file-path/wefw/2022-01-02
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wefw/wef/2021-02-03
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wef/
```

I want to remove everything after the last `/` sign, if the only thing after it resembles a date (i.e. YYYY-MM-dd or ####-##-##).

Output:

```
file_paths
my-file-path/wefw/wefw/
my-file-path/wefw/
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wefw/wef/
my-file-path/wef/wfe/wef/
```

I'm thinking of doing something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(file_paths, 'regex_here', '', 1, 'i')
FROM my_table
```

I'm unsure of how to write the RegEx for this though. I'm also open to easier methods of string manipulation, if there are any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pattern `^([^\/]+\/)+([\d-]+)?$` will match the part you want to keep in the first capturing group.

Comment: This regex does match that part, but wouldn't work directly in my query. I tried `SELECT regexp_substr(file_paths, '^([^\/]+\/)+([\d-]+)?$', 1, 1, 'e')
FROM my_table;` but am getting empty records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE ( file_paths, '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$', '/' )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OtgEtN/1).

The `/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$` is a POSIX ERE compliant pattern matching

- `/`  - a slash
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `-[0-9]{1,2}` - a hyphen and one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

If your values can contain trailing whitespace, insert `[[:space:]]*` before `$`: `/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}[[:space:]]*$`.

Answer (score -1):

You may use this regex:

```
^(.*?\/)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

You may try this query:

```
select regexp_replace(file_paths, '^(.*?\/)\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$','$1')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qlLWKi/1)

Comment: Thank you for this. This regex definitely identifies the date, but it doesn't directly work in my query, and the date doesn't get replaced with an empty string

Comment: `SELECT regexp_replace(file_paths, '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', '', 1, 'i')
FROM my_table` still returns my original input

Comment: unfortunately i dont have sql ide to to test my query in database. please check my update and let me know

Comment: Got this error `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^(.*?>>>HERE>>>/)d{4}-d{2'.`

Comment: Ok, added escape character to the query, may try now

Comment: Same error, I think this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022295/redshift-regular-expression-negative-lookahead-does-not-work

Comment: Most probably it is a posix error.  Can you please try that ? `select regexp_replace(file_paths, '^(.*?/)\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$','$1')`

Comment: Still the same exact error... `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^(.*?>>>HERE>>>/)\d{4}-\d'.`